# Facebook Graph Api doesn't redirect to my callback

Tags: facebook, fbconnect, facebook-graph-api

I am following the steps to do the authorization as described [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/), but I am not redirected to my callback url.

I get the following five steps after calling the first one:

- https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?display=touch&client_id=...&redirect_uri=...
- https://www.facebook.com/connect/uiserver.php?display=touch&client_id=...&redirect_uri=...&next=https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize_success?display=touch&client_id=...&redirect_uri=...&type=web_server&cancel_url=https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize_cancel?display=touch&client_id=...&redirect_uri=...&method=permissions.request&return_session=1
- http://www.facebook.com/
- http://touch.facebook.com/?w2m
- http://touch.facebook.com/login.php?next=http://touch.facebook.com/?w2m&cancel=http://touch.facebook.com/?w2m&fbconnect=0&r39c26cf0&refid=108

As you see the 5th step just displays the login screen. If I log in, or I am already logged in I am presented with the home page.

I use my application key, and the connect url of the app I've setup in FB Developers page.

What I am doing wrong, why I am not redirected to my url?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey, I just hit my head to the wall for two hours with this problem, until I realized I was using my Application Key instead of my Application Id. Once I fixed this it worked.
Hope it helps